# error in running tcl file when used iwidgets

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using **iwidgets** in my **tcl** script. Actually I am trying to learn how to use combobox and various such controls in tcl. So I copied a code from the net and tried to run it.
*I have installed **iwidgets** package*.
*I am using fedora 14*

when I try to run the script using the command -

> wish comb.tcl

I am getting the error -

> error in startup script: invalid command name "iwidgets:combobox".

So do I need to use something additional in the command? or do I need to install any more packages?

Comment: In comb.tcl, do you `package require Iwidgets` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your script *must* state:

```
package require Iwidgets
```

somewhere in it (which triggers the loading of the Iwidgets library and any configuration scripts relating to it). Also, you need to make sure you are naming the command correctly:

```
iwidgets::combobox .combo -labeltext "Example:"
```

In particular, that is a *double*-colon there; Tcl's namespaces use `::` as a separator, not `:` (that character can be used inside a command, namespace or variable name, though not at the start or end of each simple-name part of the name).

---

Here's a full example, which works when I try it:

```
package require Tk
package require Iwidgets
iwidgets::combobox .combo -labeltext "Example:"
.combo insert list 0 "alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta"
pack .combo
```

See [this page](http://incrtcl.sourceforge.net/iwidgets/iwidgets/combobox.html) for more info about the Iwidgets combobox, including a larger example.